# ExpressionEngine File Not Deleting

Tags: expressionengine

I work in ExpressionEngine v2.11.9 and I am trying to replace a file with an updated version and want to keep the same name so I don't have to update all the instances the file is linked on our website. However, when I delete the file and upload the new version, it replaces it with the deleted older version. We have also been experiencing files that were deleted from the Asset Manager still coming up in a search for that document in an online browser. For clarification, we have not had this problem until recently. Previously, I have been able to upload the new version of this document and "replace" the current version and it updates. Yet, it has stopped doing that. Also, when I delete a file in the Asset Manager, typically the filepath is broken when trying to access it from the website. However, in this instance, after deleting the file, it still pulls up the deleted file from the website.

Please let me know if you have any questions or require more information.

Thank you,
Beth